# What does "Ship complete" mean to you?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, meaning

I'm looking for a better way than "Ship Complete" to say "Do not ship products individually."

"Ship Complete" is an option found in an order entry process. The order process goes as follows:

1. A customer enters their order.
2. The customer chooses from a pre-determined list of delivery locations.
3. They then chooses if they would like their order's individual items to be "shipped complete" or "shipped individually".
4. Optionally the customer can add a custom message or instructions.
5. And lastly, they choose their payment method and finalize the order.

"Ship complete" in step three is easier to understand in the actual process due to headings and its relationship to "ship individually", but when you see it on an order detail page you see strictly, "Ship complete" which causes confusion.

Some potential options that have been put together are:

- Ship as complete order
- Ship as one order
- Ship 100% together
- Ship as bundle
- Ship as single unit

I'd love to have a few more options to mill over. So, how would you say, "Do not ship products individually" in a more concise way?

Comment: What is wrong with your own suggestion "Do not ship products individually"? If you can tell us why you think that's not a good solution, maybe we can suggest other ideas.

Comment: I'd prefer it said in a more concise way. The space that "Ship Complete" and "Ship Individually" isn't very big on an order detail page. So if possible I'd like to say it with fewer words.

Comment: For the record, I found this post as a result of the terrible "ship complete" language used on Canon's site. I wish any one of these answers had been the language they used.

Comment: "Ship as one delivery" or something like that seems commonly used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to suggest that going for 'concise' is not actually in you or your customers' best interests; I'd tend to use more words and more redundancy, to increase the chances that everyone understands what is intended.

To that end, I'd probably go with something like "Bundle all items together into a single delivery shipment".

Comment: That's a great point. Thanks for keeping the customer at the forefront.

Answer (score 2):

IME, "No partial orders" or "No partial shipments" appear on orders many times.